# Sagemaker Model Monitoring: Model Quality Monitoring baseline job too much data for max payload size

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently using **Sagemaker Model Monitoring** modules in order to check model and data quality. I create the data and model baselines with the `sagemaker` python API. While running the Batch Transform Job launched by the `suggest_baseline()` function with the model quality monitor, I got this error:

```
2023-07-28T15:04:37.163:[sagemaker logs]: MaxConcurrentTransforms=1, MaxPayloadInMB=6, BatchStrategy=MULTI_RECORD
2023-07-28T15:04:38.084:[sagemaker logs]: X.csv: Too much data for max payload size
```

As we can see `MaxPayloadInMB=6` so one change could be to use a bigger `MaxPayloadInMB` size. The problem is that that parameter is not configurable through the `sagemaker` model monitoring python API.

How can I deal with this problem?

**Update**:

This code below is executed into a Lambda function in order to setup a model monitor for the newly deployed model:

```py
model_quality_monitor = ModelQualityMonitor(
        role=role,
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
        volume_size_in_gb=20,
        max_runtime_in_seconds=1800,
    )

    logger.info("Suggesting baseline")
    model_quality_monitor.suggest_baseline(
        baseline_dataset=baseline_dataset_uri,
        dataset_format=DatasetFormat.csv(header=True),
        output_s3_uri=(
            f"s3://{bucket}/{endpoint_name}/{schema_version}/model-quality/baseline/results"
        ),
        problem_type="BinaryClassification",
        inference_attribute="prediction",
        probability_attribute="probability",
        ground_truth_attribute="label",
        wait=True,
        logs=True,
    )

    logger.info("Creating model quality scheduler")
    endpoint_input = EndpointInput(
        endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
        probability_attribute="0",
        probability_threshold_attribute=0.5,
        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input_data",
    )

    results_uri = (
        f"s3://{bucket}/{endpoint_name}/{schema_version}/model-quality/results"
    )

    schedule_name = f"{endpoint_name}-model-quality-monitor-schedule"
    model_quality_monitor.create_monitoring_schedule(
        monitor_schedule_name=schedule_name,
        endpoint_input=endpoint_input,
        output_s3_uri=results_uri,
        problem_type="BinaryClassification",
        ground_truth_input=f"s3://{bucket}/{endpoint_name}/{schema_version}/ground-truth",
        constraints=model_quality_monitor.latest_baselining_job.suggested_constraints(),
        schedule_cron_expression=CronExpressionGenerator.hourly(),
        enable_cloudwatch_metrics=True,
    )

    model_quality_monitor.describe_schedule()
```

Comment: Can you post monitoring job function where you are utlizing the parameter?

Comment: @yashaswik I updated the question below with the code is executed in order to configure and setup my Sagemaker Model Monitor.

Comment: mentioned error occurs when sagemaker Transformer function is run , can u confirm whether you are executing transformer function simultaneously?

Comment: @yashaswik  I don't  explicitly trigger any Transformer function. I think that the Transformer function is triggered automatically by the suggest baseline function.

Comment: what is the size of baseline data ?